# Iterating with foreach through multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

When iterating through a multidimensional array like so:

```
int arr[2][2] = {{6, 7}, {8, 3}, {5, 2}};
for (auto &row : arr) {
    for (auto &cell : row) {
        // code
    }
}
```

What is the type of `row` and `cell` and why must you use a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't use a reference array-to-pointer conversion kicks in and `row` is of type pointer to an array of two `int`s (`int(*)[2]`). The inner loop is then ill-formed because for it to work you need either:

- a type that has `begin` and `end` member functions that return iterators,
- `begin` and `end` free functions that are found by argument dependent lookup and return iterators or
- for array types, `x` and `x + bound` are used for `begin` and `end`, respectively, where `x` is the range and `bound` is the array bound.

`int(*)[2]` doesn't fullfile these conditons. OTOH, when you use `auto&`, you get `int(&)[2]` and the third bullet applies.

P.S. You've got too many initializers for `int[2][2]`.

Comment: Is the type of `row` `int *` or `int(*)[2]`? According to the book C++ primer, it says that the type of `row` is `int *`. Please refer to [Using a Range for with Multidimensional Arrays](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=J1HMLyxqJfgC&lpg=PT268&ots=FJNBVd5hdq&dq=As%20a%20result%2C%20in%20this%20loop%20the%20type%20of%20row%20is%20int*.%20The%20inner%20for%20loop%20is%20illegal.%20Despite%20our%20intentions%2C%20that%20loop%20attempts%20to%20iterate%20over%20an%20int*.&pg=PT268#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

`row` is an array of `int`s.  `cell` is a reference to an `int`.  You need a reference if you want to modify the contents of `cell`, because otherwise the loop variable will be a copy.